Extracting List into a Subview broke NavigationStack
I had homepageTab with a NavigationStack inside it and a listView that navigated to a detailView:
static var fetchDescriptor: FetchDescriptor<Workout> {
    let date = Date.now
    let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Workout>(
        // predicate: #Predicate { $0.endTime == selectedDate },
        sortBy: [
            .init(\.endTime, order: .reverse)
        ]
    )


   //descriptor.fetchLimit = 6
    return descriptor
}

// Use Query with FetchDescriptor
@Query(fetchDescriptor) var workouts: [Workout]

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
     
    Group {
        if workouts.isEmpty {
            ContentUnavailableView {
                Label("No workouts yet", systemImage: "dumbbell.fill")
            } description: {
                Text("Tap the button below to get started")
            }
        actions: {
            NavigationLink {
                AddWorkoutView()
                
            } label : {
                Text("Start Workout")
                    .underline()
                
            }
        }
        }
        
        else {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Recent Workouts")) {
                    ForEach(workouts) { workout in
                        NavigationLink {
                            EditWorkoutView(workout: workout)
                                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                        }
                        //The UI of each List Item
                    label: { HStack(spacing: 19)
                        {
                            
                            if showDuplicateButton {
                                Button {
                                    //the workout copy method uses the exercises copy method to copy all exercises which itself does the same for its sets
                                    let newWorkout = workout.copy()
                                    modelContext.insert(newWorkout)
                                    showDuplicateButton.toggle()
                                    
                                }
                            label: {
                                Image(systemName: "plus.rectangle.on.rectangle")
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                            }
                            
                            //i know this wont be nil but still best to provide a default anyway
                            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                Text(workout.endTime.formatted(.dateTime.weekday()))
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                                    .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 5)
                                    .padding([.bottom], 2)
                                    .background(Color(red: 70/255, green: 130/255, blue: 180/255))
                                    .clipShape(
                                        .rect(
                                            topLeadingRadius: 5,
                                            bottomLeadingRadius: 0,
                                            bottomTrailingRadius: 0,
                                            topTrailingRadius: 5
                                        )
                                    )
                                Text(workout.endTime.formatted(.dateTime.day(.twoDigits)))
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                    .padding([.top], 2)
                                    .padding([.bottom], 5)
                            }
                            .frame(width: 42)
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                    .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.4), lineWidth: 1)
                            )
                            
                            
                            //chatgpt why is my workout.name and exercises text not aligned?
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                                Text(workout.name)
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .semibold, design: .default))
                                
                                //The Stats
                                if let exercises =  workout.exercises {
                                    Text("\(exercises.count)x Exercises")
                                        .font(.system(size: 13))
                                }
                                
                            } }
                    }
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            } //end list
            
            
        }
    }

But then I extracted that list to a subview and now that navigationLink isn't working at all before it would go to the editWorkoutView and now it just breaks the entire nav stack:
struct WorkoutListView: View {
    
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    
    @Query var workouts: [Workout]
    var selectedDate : Date
    
    var showDuplicateButton: Bool
        
    init(sort: SortDescriptor<Workout>, selectedDate: Date, showDuplicateButton: Bool) {
        self.showDuplicateButton = showDuplicateButton
        self.selectedDate = selectedDate
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let startOfMonth = calendar.date(from: calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: selectedDate))!
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.month = 1
        components.second = -1
        let endOfMonth = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: startOfMonth)!
        
        let predicate = #Predicate<Workout> {
            $0.endTime >= startOfMonth && $0.endTime < endOfMonth
        }
        
        _workouts = Query(filter: predicate,sort: [sort])
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Recent Workouts")) {
                ForEach(workouts) { workout in
                    NavigationLink {
                        EditWorkoutView(workout: workout)
                            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    }
                    //The UI of each List Item
                label: { HStack(spacing: 19)
                    {
                        
                        if showDuplicateButton {
                            Button {
                                //the workout copy method uses the exercises copy method to copy all exercises which itself does the same for its sets
                                let newWorkout = workout.copy()
                                modelContext.insert(newWorkout)
                                //showDuplicateButton.toggle()
                                
                            }
                        label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.rectangle.on.rectangle")
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                        }
                        
                        //i know this wont be nil but still best to provide a default anyway
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            Text(workout.endTime.formatted(.dateTime.weekday()))
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                .font(.system(size: 14))
                                .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 5)
                                .padding([.bottom], 2)
                                .background(Color(red: 70/255, green: 130/255, blue: 180/255))
                                .clipShape(
                                    .rect(
                                        topLeadingRadius: 5,
                                        bottomLeadingRadius: 0,
                                        bottomTrailingRadius: 0,
                                        topTrailingRadius: 5
                                    )
                                )
                            Text(workout.endTime.formatted(.dateTime.day(.twoDigits)))
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .font(.system(size: 16))
                                .padding([.top], 2)
                                .padding([.bottom], 5)
                        }
                        .frame(width: 42)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.4), lineWidth: 1)
                        )
                        
                        
                        //chatgpt why is my workout.name and exercises text not aligned?
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                            Text(workout.name)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .semibold, design: .default))
                            
                            //The Stats
                            if let exercises =  workout.exercises {
                                Text("\(exercises.count)x Exercises")
                                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }

How do you keep your navigationLinks working when extracting views into subviews?
